# Setting up a development server for mobile applications

Tags: android, ios, localhost, backend

How does one set up a development server for mobile apps?

In web development developers usually install [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) and then use localhost to communicate with the server and test in a safe environment. This is a free and fast working solution, since it requires very little or no upload time. What is an equivalent for mobile developers on the iOS or Android platform? Some kind of localhost for mobile app developers.

The goal is to develop a backend for a mobile app in a safe and quick environment. Their exact equivalent for web developers is using localhost.

Example: The user registers. Username and password along with an image are sent to the server and stored in the database. The next time the user logs in the server looks up in the database and serves the correct image to the user and logs him/her in.

I am not asking for how to program this or what code to use. I am asking for instructions to a set up developer test environment - a localhost for mobile apps, if such a thing exists.

Comment: You want to set up a server that will run in your application? What is your use case?

Comment: Yeah app is client, and asks server for a data. server responds, app asks for new data and so on.  nothing special. I am looking for a way to test ideas. I know that I would need a server at some point. PCs use localhost to develop and test out. What do mobile app developers use?

Comment: @krompir2 see http://parse.com

Comment: Your question is very broad and unspecific. There are million of ways how to do it.  You can have something very simple that serves only static web-pages/json-files, or go with more complex and dynamic solutions using Ruby/Node.js/PHP/Python-base frameworks. It depends on your what requirements are. Can you elaborate a bit more? Can you give some examples of what you want to achieve? Is it a simple feed reader, cloud data storage, or photo server, or blog/twitter like server, something else?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, web developers, can quickly set your localhost by installing XAMPP or any equivalent web server, a database server like [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) on localhost. They put their web services on a web server and call or use them from the front end (HTML page) on user actions like form submissions, button clicks, etc.

Mobile application development with Android is very much similar to the above approach. All web services lie at the back end, and you only call them from an Android client (mobile device) using the HttpClient or HttpUrlConnection class.

You can make only HTTP requests from a mobile application and get a response from the services which are called, parse the response and populate the UI elements.

You can set up your localhost with a database server, a web server as you mentioned correctly above. Now to make a request from your mobile device to localhost, keep your device and localhost machine on the same network (you can put both devices on the same Wi-Fi network) so that you can directly make requests to your localhost from your mobile application. You will get a response in the mobile app in whichever format you have provided and use it. This is very similar to that of web application, where you can imagine your UI lying in mobile device which was an HTML page in a web application.

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for. Thank you! I will leave the question open for a while if anyone has anything to add.

Comment: Its my pleasure , that I could help . :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a web server / server application installed on your machine, then the requirement is that the device and server can communicate.

This is normally done using the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class. You will need the IP address of your server in order to construct your URL, that is instead of accessing your server application using `localhost/myapp` you will need to add the url `192.168.0.255/my app` (or whatever your actual IP address is).

There are a couple of issues to watch out for. Your development machine must accept incoming http requests (port 80 normally) through the firewall, and your router must allow the traffic between the machine and the device. Have a look at http://portforward.com/ if you are having trouble with this. If you are having trouble diagnosing the issues, then sometimes downloading a terminal app on the device can help.

Sometimes cheap routers or corporate policies make this difficult. In this case you can try [setting up a portable hotspot](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/mobile-phone/how-tether-google-android-phone-image-3279408/) or creating an ad-hoc network if your server machine also has a wireless network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a mobile app then I would think you want to keep focussed on the mobile development part and therefore mock out the backend rather than write a working server with a database, logic, etc.

In very simple cases I would recommend using something such as [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). This allows you to intercept requests in and out of your mobile app either from the simulator or device and validate everything is working as expected at a call by call level. If you want something more persistent then using a simple web framework in your language of choice with fixed responses would do the job well. For example, [Sinatra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinatra_%28software%29) for [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) or [Express.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express.js) for [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js). And then rather than worrying about having a database to maintain and seed, just return fixed [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) responses for a particular call or a file from disk. This could then be committed with your mobile development code repositories and used as part of test suites.